# Amazon EC2 error while launching instances The maximum number of VPCs has been reached

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to create a Python program using boto3 that creates an Amazon AutoScaling group. Define scale up and scale down policies and corresponding CloudWatch alarms. Supply the startup script  created in previous step while launching a new instance from the program. Using a security group port 80 open,
here is the program ,

```
# Check if the user has the Access & Secret key configured
import boto3
from boto3 import Session

session = Session()
credentials = session.get_credentials()
current_credentials = credentials.get_frozen_credentials()

# Break & Exit if any of the key is not present
if current_credentials.access_key is None:
    print("Access Key missing, use  `aws configure` to setup")
    exit()

if current_credentials.secret_key is None:
    print("Secret Key missing, use  `aws configure` to setup")
    exit()

# VPC design for multi az deployments
globalVars = {}
globalVars['REGION_NAME']              = "ap-south-1"
globalVars['AZ1']                      = "ap-south-1a"
globalVars['AZ2']                      = "ap-south-1b"
globalVars['CIDRange']                 = "10.240.0.0/23"
globalVars['az1_pvtsubnet_CIDRange']   = "10.240.0.0/25"
globalVars['az1_pubsubnet_CIDRange']   = "10.240.0.128/26"
globalVars['az1_sparesubnet_CIDRange'] = "10.240.0.192/26"
globalVars['az2_pvtsubnet_CIDRange']   = "10.240.1.0/25"
globalVars['az2_pubsubnet_CIDRange']   = "10.240.1.128/26"
globalVars['az2_sparesubnet_CIDRange'] = "10.240.1.192/26"
globalVars['Project']                  = { 'Key': 'Name',        'Value': 'test1'}
globalVars['tags']                     = [{'Key': 'Owner',       'Value': 'test1'},
                                          {'Key': 'Environment', 'Value': 'Test'},
                                          {'Key': 'Department',  'Value': 'TestD'}]
# EC2 Parameters

globalVars['EC2-Amazon-AMI-ID']        = "ami-d783a9b8"
globalVars['EC2-InstanceType']         = "t2.micro"
globalVars['EC2-KeyName']              = "datastructutre key"

# AutoScaling Parameters
globalVars['ASG-LaunchConfigName']     = "ASG-Demo-LaunchConfig"
globalVars['ASG-AutoScalingGroupName'] = "ASG-Demo-AutoScalingGrp"


# Creating a VPC, Subnet, and Gateway
ec2       = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name=globalVars['REGION_NAME'])
ec2Client = boto3.client('ec2',   region_name=globalVars['REGION_NAME'])
vpc       = ec2.create_vpc(CidrBlock=globalVars['CIDRange'])
asgClient = boto3.client('autoscaling', region_name=globalVars['REGION_NAME'])
rds       = boto3.client('rds', region_name=globalVars['REGION_NAME'])

# AZ1 Subnets
az1_pvtsubnet   = vpc.create_subnet(CidrBlock=globalVars['az1_pvtsubnet_CIDRange'],   AvailabilityZone=globalVars['AZ1'])
az1_pubsubnet   = vpc.create_subnet(CidrBlock=globalVars['az1_pubsubnet_CIDRange'],   AvailabilityZone=globalVars['AZ1'])
az1_sparesubnet = vpc.create_subnet(CidrBlock=globalVars['az1_sparesubnet_CIDRange'], AvailabilityZone=globalVars['AZ1'])
# AZ2 Subnet
az2_pvtsubnet   = vpc.create_subnet(CidrBlock=globalVars['az2_pvtsubnet_CIDRange'],   AvailabilityZone=globalVars['AZ2'])
az2_pubsubnet   = vpc.create_subnet(CidrBlock=globalVars['az2_pubsubnet_CIDRange'],   AvailabilityZone=globalVars['AZ2'])
az2_sparesubnet = vpc.create_subnet(CidrBlock=globalVars['az2_sparesubnet_CIDRange'], AvailabilityZone=globalVars['AZ2'])

# Enable DNS Hostnames in the VPC
vpc.modify_attribute(EnableDnsSupport={'Value': True})
vpc.modify_attribute(EnableDnsHostnames={'Value': True})

# Create the Internet Gatway & Attach to the VPC
intGateway = ec2.create_internet_gateway()
intGateway.attach_to_vpc(VpcId=vpc.id)

# Create another route table for Public & Private traffic
routeTable = ec2.create_route_table(VpcId=vpc.id)
rtbAssn=[]
rtbAssn.append(routeTable.associate_with_subnet(SubnetId=az1_pubsubnet.id))
rtbAssn.append(routeTable.associate_with_subnet(SubnetId=az1_pvtsubnet.id))
rtbAssn.append(routeTable.associate_with_subnet(SubnetId=az2_pubsubnet.id))
rtbAssn.append(routeTable.associate_with_subnet(SubnetId=az2_pvtsubnet.id))

# Create a route for internet traffic to flow out
intRoute = ec2Client.create_route(RouteTableId=routeTable.id, DestinationCidrBlock='0.0.0.0/0', GatewayId=intGateway.id)

# Tag the resources
vpc.create_tags            (Tags=globalVars['tags'])
az1_pvtsubnet.create_tags  (Tags=globalVars['tags'])
az1_pubsubnet.create_tags  (Tags=globalVars['tags'])
az1_sparesubnet.create_tags(Tags=globalVars['tags'])
az2_pvtsubnet.create_tags  (Tags=globalVars['tags'])
az2_pubsubnet.create_tags  (Tags=globalVars['tags'])
az2_sparesubnet.create_tags(Tags=globalVars['tags'])
intGateway.create_tags     (Tags=globalVars['tags'])
routeTable.create_tags     (Tags=globalVars['tags'])

vpc.create_tags            (Tags=[{'Key': 'Name', 'Value': globalVars['Project']['Value'] + '-vpc'}])
az1_pvtsubnet.create_tags  (Tags=[{'Key': 'Name', 'Value': globalVars['Project']['Value'] + '-az1-private-subnet'}])
az1_pubsubnet.create_tags  (Tags=[{'Key': 'Name', 'Value': globalVars['Project']['Value'] + '-az1-public-subnet'}])
az1_sparesubnet.create_tags(Tags=[{'Key': 'Name', 'Value': globalVars['Project']['Value'] + '-az1-spare-subnet'}])
az2_pvtsubnet.create_tags  (Tags=[{'Key': 'Name', 'Value': globalVars['Project']['Value'] + '-az2-private-subnet'}])
az2_pubsubnet.create_tags  (Tags=[{'Key': 'Name', 'Value': globalVars['Project']['Value'] + '-az2-public-subnet'}])
az2_sparesubnet.create_tags(Tags=[{'Key': 'Name', 'Value': globalVars['Project']['Value'] + '-az2-spare-subnet'}])
intGateway.create_tags     (Tags=[{'Key': 'Name', 'Value': globalVars['Project']['Value'] + '-igw'}])
routeTable.create_tags     (Tags=[{'Key': 'Name', 'Value': globalVars['Project']['Value'] + '-rtb'}])

# Let create the Public & Private Security Groups
elbSecGrp = ec2.create_security_group(DryRun=False,
                                      GroupName='elbSecGrp',
                                      Description='ElasticLoadBalancer_Security_Group',
                                      VpcId=vpc.id
                                      )

pubSecGrp = ec2.create_security_group(DryRun=False,
                                      GroupName='pubSecGrp',
                                      Description='Public_Security_Group',
                                      VpcId=vpc.id
                                      )

pvtSecGrp = ec2.create_security_group(DryRun=False,
                                      GroupName='pvtSecGrp',
                                      Description='Private_Security_Group',
                                      VpcId=vpc.id
                                      )

elbSecGrp.create_tags(Tags=globalVars['tags'])
pubSecGrp.create_tags(Tags=globalVars['tags'])
pvtSecGrp.create_tags(Tags=globalVars['tags'])

elbSecGrp.create_tags(Tags=[{'Key': 'Name', 'Value': globalVars['Project']['Value'] + '-elb-security-group'}])
pubSecGrp.create_tags(Tags=[{'Key': 'Name', 'Value': globalVars['Project']['Value'] + '-public-security-group'}])
pvtSecGrp.create_tags(Tags=[{'Key': 'Name', 'Value': globalVars['Project']['Value'] + '-private-security-group'}])

# Add a rule that allows inbound SSH, HTTP, HTTPS traffic ( from any source )
ec2Client.authorize_security_group_ingress(GroupId=elbSecGrp.id,
                                           IpProtocol='tcp',
                                           FromPort=80,
                                           ToPort=80,
                                           CidrIp='0.0.0.0/0'
                                           )

# Allow Public Security Group to receive traffic from ELB Security group
ec2Client.authorize_security_group_ingress(GroupId=pubSecGrp.id,
                                           IpPermissions=[{'IpProtocol': 'tcp',
                                                           'FromPort': 80,
                                                           'ToPort': 80,
                                                           'UserIdGroupPairs': [{'GroupId': elbSecGrp.id}]
                                                           }]
                                           )
# Allow Private Security Group to receive traffic from Application Security group
ec2Client.authorize_security_group_ingress(GroupId=pvtSecGrp.id,
                                           IpPermissions=[{'IpProtocol': 'tcp',
                                                           'FromPort': 3306,
                                                           'ToPort': 3306,
                                                           'UserIdGroupPairs': [{'GroupId': pubSecGrp.id}]
                                                           }]
                                           )

ec2Client.authorize_security_group_ingress(GroupId=pubSecGrp.id,
                                           IpProtocol='tcp',
                                           FromPort=80,
                                           ToPort=80,
                                           CidrIp='0.0.0.0/0'
                                           )
ec2Client.authorize_security_group_ingress(GroupId=pubSecGrp.id,
                                           IpProtocol='tcp',
                                           FromPort=443,
                                           ToPort=443,
                                           CidrIp='0.0.0.0/0'
                                           )
ec2Client.authorize_security_group_ingress(GroupId=pubSecGrp.id,
                                           IpProtocol='tcp',
                                           FromPort=22,
                                           ToPort=22,
                                           CidrIp='0.0.0.0/0'
                                           )


# The user defined code to install  WebServer & Configure them
userDataCode = """
#!/bin/bash
set -e -x
# Setting up the HTTP server 
yum install -y httpd 
service httpd start
chkconfig httpd on
groupadd www
usermod -a -G www ec2-user
cd /var/www/
# Set the permissions
chown -R root:www /var/www
chmod 2775 /var/www
find /var/www -type d -exec chmod 2775 {} +
find /var/www -type f -exec chmod 0664 {} +
# SE Linux permissive
# setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1
service httpd restart
# Remove below file after testing
echo "<?php phpinfo(); ?>" > /var/www/html/phptestinfo.php
"""

# Create the  Public Instance
##### **DeviceIndex**:The network interface's position in the attachment order. For example, the first attached network interface has a DeviceIndex of 0
instanceLst = ec2.create_instances(ImageId=globalVars['EC2-Amazon-AMI-ID'],
                                   MinCount=1,
                                   MaxCount=1,
                                   KeyName="datastructutre key",
                                   UserData=userDataCode,
                                   InstanceType=globalVars['EC2-InstanceType'],
                                   NetworkInterfaces=[
                                       {
                                           'SubnetId': az1_pubsubnet.id,
                                           'Groups': [pubSecGrp.id],
                                           'DeviceIndex': 0,
                                           'DeleteOnTermination': True,
                                           'AssociatePublicIpAddress': True,
                                       }
                                   ]
                                   )


# Create the Launch Configuration
# InstanceId = 'string'
asgLaunchConfig = asgClient.create_launch_configuration(
    LaunchConfigurationName=globalVars['ASG-LaunchConfigName'],
    ImageId=globalVars['EC2-Amazon-AMI-ID'],
    KeyName=globalVars['EC2-KeyName'],
    SecurityGroups=[pubSecGrp.id],
    UserData=userDataCode,
    InstanceType=globalVars['EC2-InstanceType'],
    InstanceMonitoring={'Enabled': False },
    EbsOptimized=False,
    AssociatePublicIpAddress=False
)

# create Auto-Scaling Group
ASGSubnets = az1_pubsubnet.id + "," +az2_pubsubnet.id
asGroup=asgClient.create_auto_scaling_group(
    AutoScalingGroupName=globalVars['ASG-AutoScalingGroupName'],
    LaunchConfigurationName=globalVars['ASG-LaunchConfigName'],
    MinSize=1,
    MaxSize=3,
    DesiredCapacity=2,
    DefaultCooldown=120,
    HealthCheckType='EC2',
    HealthCheckGracePeriod=60,
    Tags=globalVars['tags'],
    VPCZoneIdentifier=ASGSubnets
    )

asgClient.create_or_update_tags(
    Tags=[
        {
            'ResourceId': globalVars['ASG-AutoScalingGroupName'],
            'ResourceType': 'auto-scaling-group',
            'Key': 'Name',
            'Value': globalVars['Project']['Value'] + '-ASG-Group',
            'PropagateAtLaunch': True
        },
    ]
)



###### Print to Screen ########
print("VPC ID                    : {0}".format(vpc.id))
print("AZ1 Public Subnet ID      : {0}".format(az1_pubsubnet.id))
print("AZ1 Private Subnet ID     : {0}".format(az1_pvtsubnet.id))
print("AZ1 Spare Subnet ID       : {0}".format(az1_sparesubnet.id))
print("Internet Gateway ID       : {0}".format(intGateway.id))
print("Route Table ID            : {0}".format(routeTable.id))
print("Public Security Group ID  : {0}".format(pubSecGrp.id))
print("Private Security Group ID : {0}".format(pvtSecGrp.id))
print("EC2 Key Pair              : {0}".format(globalVars['EC2-KeyName']))
print("EC2 PublicIP              : {0}".format(globalVars['EC2-KeyName']))
print("RDS Endpoint              : {0}".format(globalVars['Endpoint']))
###### Print to Screen ########


"""
Function to clean up all the resources
"""
def cleanAll(resourcesDict=None):
    # Delete the instances
    ids = []
    for i in instanceLst:
        ids.append(i.id)

    ec2.instances.filter(InstanceIds=ids).terminate()

    # Wait for the instance to be terminated
    waiter = ec2Client.get_waiter('instance_terminated')
    waiter.wait(InstanceIds=[ids])
    ec2Client.delete_key_pair(KeyName=globalVars['EC2-KeyName'])

    # Delete Routes & Routing Table
    for assn in rtbAssn:
        ec2Client.disassociate_route_table(AssociationId=assn.id)

    routeTable.delete()

    # Delete Subnets
    az1_pvtsubnet.delete()
    az1_pubsubnet.delete()
    az1_sparesubnet.delete()

    # Detach & Delete internet Gateway
    ec2Client.detach_internet_gateway(InternetGatewayId=intGateway.id, VpcId=vpc.id)
    intGateway.delete()

    # Delete Security Groups
    pubSecGrp.delete()
    pvtSecGrp.delete()

    vpc.delete()
```

how ever I have not reached that stage to write scale up and scale down policies for cloud watch alarms in the above code, it is just that while executing it before proceeding further I got following errors,

```
autoscaling.py", line 51, in <module>
    vpc       = ec2.create_vpc(CidrBlock=globalVars['CIDRange'])
  File "E:\installation2\python3\lib\site-packages\boto3\resources\factory.py", line 520, in do_action
    response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\installation2\python3\lib\site-packages\boto3\resources\action.py", line 83, in __call__
    response = getattr(parent.meta.client, operation_name)(**params)
  File "E:\installation2\python3\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 314, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "E:\installation2\python3\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 612, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (VpcLimitExceeded) when calling the CreateVpc operation: The maximum number of VPCs has been reached.
```

What should I do to get rid of this error :The maximum number of VPCs has been reached.
 , I use free tier services of amazon.

The output of aws ec2 describe-security-groups is following

```
   {
    "SecurityGroups": [
        {
            "Description": "default VPC security group",
            "GroupName": "default",
            "IpPermissions": [
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "-1",
                    "IpRanges": [],
                    "Ipv6Ranges": [],
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": [
                        {
                            "GroupId": "sg-03c0e0d31aca5827b",
                            "UserId": "101010101010"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "OwnerId": "101010101010",
            "GroupId": "sg-03c0e0d31aca5827b",
            "IpPermissionsEgress": [
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "-1",
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Ipv6Ranges": [],
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": []
                }
            ],
            "VpcId": "vpc-06eedbb5dc8c8e20b"
        },
        {
            "Description": "default VPC security group",
            "GroupName": "default",
            "IpPermissions": [
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "-1",
                    "IpRanges": [],
                    "Ipv6Ranges": [],
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": [
                        {
                            "GroupId": "sg-080f42f6c90e60956",
                            "UserId": "101010101010"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "OwnerId": "101010101010",
            "GroupId": "sg-080f42f6c90e60956",
            "IpPermissionsEgress": [
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "-1",
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Ipv6Ranges": [],
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": []
                }
            ],
            "VpcId": "vpc-0a0a0699b064d3382"
        },
        {
            "Description": "default VPC security group",
            "GroupName": "default",
            "IpPermissions": [
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "-1",
                    "IpRanges": [],
                    "Ipv6Ranges": [],
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": [
                        {
                            "GroupId": "sg-096d48a3a161a98cc",
                            "UserId": "101010101010"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "OwnerId": "101010101010",
            "GroupId": "sg-096d48a3a161a98cc",
            "IpPermissionsEgress": [
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "-1",
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Ipv6Ranges": [],
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": []
                }
            ],
            "VpcId": "vpc-090b6525d5e4166bd"
        },
        {
            "Description": "default VPC security group",
            "GroupName": "default",
            "IpPermissions": [
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "-1",
                    "IpRanges": [],
                    "Ipv6Ranges": [],
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": [
                        {
                            "GroupId": "sg-0aea8c83e780f8bca",
                            "UserId": "101010101010"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "OwnerId": "101010101010",
            "GroupId": "sg-0aea8c83e780f8bca",
            "IpPermissionsEgress": [
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "-1",
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Ipv6Ranges": [],
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": []
                }
            ],
            "VpcId": "vpc-0cf43d41666c21f82"
        },
        {
            "Description": "launch-wizard-1 created 2018-08-01T09:57:51.176+05:30",
            "GroupName": "launch-wizard-1",
            "IpPermissions": [
                {
                    "FromPort": 80,
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Ipv6Ranges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIpv6": "::/0"
                        }
                    ],
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "ToPort": 80,
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": []
                },
                {
                    "FromPort": 22,
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Ipv6Ranges": [],
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "ToPort": 22,
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": []
                }
            ],
            "OwnerId": "101010101010",
            "GroupId": "sg-0e81c2a33e1039f58",
            "IpPermissionsEgress": [
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "-1",
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Ipv6Ranges": [],
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": []
                }
            ],
            "VpcId": "vpc-08356c60"
        },
        {
            "Description": "default VPC security group",
            "GroupName": "default",
            "IpPermissions": [
                {
                    "FromPort": 80,
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Ipv6Ranges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIpv6": "::/0"
                        }
                    ],
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "ToPort": 80,
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": []
                },
                {
                    "FromPort": 22,
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Ipv6Ranges": [],
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "ToPort": 22,
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": []
                }
            ],
            "OwnerId": "101010101010",
            "GroupId": "sg-40e5492a",
            "IpPermissionsEgress": [
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "-1",
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Ipv6Ranges": [],
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": []
                }
            ],
            "VpcId": "vpc-08356c60"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have 6 vpc all mentioning defalt logged in to web console don't know command line output to find them
here are they

```
vpc-06eedbb5dc8c8e20b
vpc-0a0a0699b064d3382
vpc-090b6525d5e4166bd
vpc-0cf43d41666c21f82
launch-wizard-1 created 2018-08-01T09:57:51.176+05:30
vpc-0a0a0699b064d3382
```

the description of all of them reads Default VPC security group.
Basically what I am trying to achieve is to create an auto-scaling configuration for the web tier of a cloud application. Following the steps below.
  Create a static website with one or two HTML pages and copy the pages and dependent files in an Amazon S3 bucket.
  Create a startup script to install Apache server and copy the website files from S3 to the instance.
  Create a Python program using boto that creates an Amazon AutoScaling group. Define 
scale up and scale down policies and corresponding CloudWatch alarms. Supply the 
startup script you created in previous step while launching a new instance from the 
program. Use a security group port 80 open.
  Open the public DNS of the newly launched instance in a browser and verify if the static 
website works.
What I have not been able to do above is set cloudwatch alarms and metrics and see how they run in my code.

Comment: How many VPCs do you have defined in that region?

Comment: By the way, the traditional way to do this type of thing is to use AWS CloudFormation rather than coding it yourself.

Comment: The soft limit for VPC is 5 per region , how many have you used ?

Comment: The [AWS Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) only impacts pricing. It has no impact on the services available in your account.

Comment: there are 6 vpc if I am not mistaken in

Answer (score 5):

You don't want to create a new VPC each time. So get rid of your ec2.create_vpc call. Instead just define your vpc variable from a describe vpcs call (don't know what that is off the top of my head in boto3) - probably something like ec2.describe_vpcs -> then select whatever one you want to use. Or just hard code the vpc id in your script.

@Kush is correct - there is a soft limit of 5 VPCs per region but you don't really need to create new VPCs for everything you do. If you need to segment different aspects of you AWS infrastructure for security reasons you can rely on subnet ACLs and security groups to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it might be that by design the number of VPCs
should be bigger than 5 (default value).

To have this error fixed you need to
check the Service Quotas page in your account:

Select the nested pages in the Service Quotas page:
Service Quotas -> AWS services -> Amazon Virtual Private Cloud (Amazon VPC)

and check the value:
VPCs per Region

By default it is set to 5, you need to click the button:
Request increase at account leval
and set the desired value, let's say 10.

AWS team will review your request and update the default service quota value.